# Rearrangement of absolutely convergent series is absolutely convergent??

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent, is it true that every rearrangement of $\sum a_n$ is also "absolutely" convergent?

I know that by the Rearrangement Thm., every rearrangement of $\sum a_n$ is convergent and converges to the same value but I'm curious about the absolute convergence of them. Is this true and how would you prove it?? Any idea will be helpful!

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: @FisiaiLusia Okay. Could you give me an idea about how to prove it?

Comment: Use Riemann's rearrangement's theorem (and the fact that a rearrangement of a rearrangement is still a rearrangement).

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\sum_n a_n$ is absolutely convergent if and only if $\sum_n |a_n|$ is finite. But since $\sum_n |a_n|$ is also absolutely convergent, then any reordering $\sum_n |a_{n_j}|$ has the same finite value, so $\sum_j a_{n_j}$ is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

If $\varphi :\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} $ is bijection and $b_n =a_{\varphi (n) }$ then we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_n | =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{\varphi (n) } | =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{\varphi^{-1}\circ \varphi (n) } | =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n} | <\infty$$